# regex to clean up url

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to get a valid url out of a string like:

```
$string = 'http://somesite.com/directory//sites/9/my_forms/3-895a3e/somefilename.jpg|:||:||:||:|19845';
```

My original solution was:

```
preg_match('#^[^:|]*#', str_replace('//', '/', $string), $modifiedPath);
```

But obviously its going to remove a slash from the http:// instead of the one in the middle of the string.

My expected output that I want from the original is:

```
http://somesite.com/directory/sites/9/my_forms/3-895a3e/somefilename.jpg
```

I could always break off the http part of the string first but would like a more elegant solution in the form of regex if possible. Thanks.

Comment: This could be helpfull: `parse_url()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: What mangled them in the first place?

Comment: @Bondye `parse_url()` will just set all characters after the .com/ as 'path'. It will not cleanup the double slashes and stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do exactly what you are asking:

```
 <?php

$string = 'http://somesite.com/directory//sites/9/my_forms/3-895a3e/somefilename.jpg|:||:||:||:|19845';

preg_match('/^([^|]+)/', $string, $m); // get everything up to and NOT including the first pipe (|)
$string = $m[1];

$string = preg_replace('/(?<!:)\/\//', '/' ,$string); // replace all occurrences of // as long as they are not preceded by :

echo $string; // outputs: http://somesite.com/directory/sites/9/my_forms/3-895a3e/somefilename.jpg

exit;

 ?>
```

**EDIT:**

`(?<!X)` in regular expressions is the syntax for what is called a lookbehind.  The X is replaced with the character(s) we are testing for.

The following expression would match every instance of double slashes (/):

```
\/\/
```

But we need to make sure that the match we are looking for is NOT preceded by the : character so we need to 'lookbehind' our match to see if the : character is there.  If it is then we don't want it to be counted as a match:

```
(?<!:)\/\/
```

The ! is what says NOT to match in our lookbehind.  If we changed it to `(?=:)\/\/` then it would only match the double slashes that did have the : preceding them.

Here is a Quick tutorial that can explain it all better than I can  [lookahead and lookbehind tutorial](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/1480.htm)

Comment: Drew. I actually like this solution and appreciate the comments. Can you explain to me what the ?<! does? I can't seem to find an explanation on line. Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn `(?<!:)` is a negative zero-width look-behind assertion; its purpose is to indicate that the pattern may not be preceded by a `:` character. Here's [an exhaustive treatment of zero-width assertions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444); that said, they complicate the mental model of how a regular expression behaves to such an extent that it's best to avoid them where possible.

Comment: @AaronMiller,  sounds scary!  But really not that hard to understand.

Comment: @Shawn, I edited my answer to explain what is going on in the expression.

Comment: @Drew I didn't say it's hard to understand; I said its presence in a regex makes figuring out what that regex does significantly more complicated than otherwise, and it's therefore preferable, [per Kernighan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103299/help-me-understand-this-brian-kernighan-quote), to avoid look-around assertions where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your strings are in the form given, you don't need any but the simplest of regexes to do this; if you want an elegant solution, then a regex is definitely not what you need. Also, double slashes are legal in a URL, just like in a Unix path, and mean the same thing a single slash does, so you don't really need to get rid of them at all.

Why not just

```
$url = array_shift(preg_split('/\|/', $string));
```

?

If you really, really care about getting rid of the double slashes in the URL, then you can follow this with

```
$url = preg_replace('/([^:])\/\//', '$1/', $url);
```

or even combine them into

```
$url = preg_replace('/([^:])\/\//', '$1/', array_shift(preg_split('/\|/', $string)));
```

although that last form gets a little bit hairy.

Comment: It doesn't work.  your solution still contains the double slash in the URL

Comment: @Drew Yes, and double slashes are legal and ignored in URLs, so why do you care about them?

Comment: @Drew That said, it's trivial to clean up the double slashes if they matter to you for aesthetic reasons, and I've just updated my answer to include the method for same.

Comment: Aaron I didn't realize the // was actually valid so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Shawn Certainly! It's kind of obscure; I've been a professional web developer for a decade, and I only found out about it last year. (Granted, the superfluous slashes can break naive URI parsers and are thus best avoided anyway, but if you can't control what you're receiving and aren't passing the result to anything that'll break on them, they may be safely ignored.)

Comment: Aaron I gave you the upvote for your samples and explanations which have really helped! Due to your comments I only needed the preg_match part of Drew's initial solution so he got the vote. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a quite strictly defined situation, I'd consider just one preg to be the most elegant solution.

From the top of my head:

```
$sanitizedURL = preg_replace('~((?<!:)/(?=/)|\\|.+)~', '', $rawURL);
```

Basically, what this does is look for any forward slash that IS NOT preceded by a colon (:), and IS followed bij another forward slash. It also searches for any pipe character and any character following it.

Anything found is removed from the result.

I can explain the RegEx in more detail if you like.